# Stripped names of columns in Hibernate SQL query

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

In my Spring Boot application I am using PostgreSQL as underlying database. For debugging purposes I turned on displaying the query in console.

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

When a query is sent to database, it's shown in the console. The names of columns etc. used there do not correspond although to names from my database. For instance:

```
select
    acceptedna0_.pkey as pkey1_0_,
    acceptedna0_.name_accepted as name_acc2_0_,
    acceptedna0_.station_pkey as station_3_0_ 
from
    station_names_accepted acceptedna0_ 
where
    acceptedna0_.name_accepted=?
```

It looks as if they have been shortened or something. How can I turn this off, so that I can see the actual query?

Also: is it possible to see the actual underlying PostgreSQL query? It would help me a lot.

Comment: But you got actual query. Names with `_` are aliases

Comment: That's the way Hibernate works. I don't think you can change the aliases that the obfusaction layer generates

Comment: What you see there **is** the actual, underlying Postgres query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how SQL works; it allows you to define runtime aliases to eg. shorten SQL statements, make it more human friendly or -in this case- suit your particular use case which is result set to POJO mapping.

And now

```
from
    station_names_accepted acceptedna0_
```

means: "lets alias `station_names_accepted` table with name `acceptedna0_`"

From now on, in whole query, instead of using `station_names_accepted` you can refer to that table using the alias `acceptedna0_`.

Normally you would name it like `sna` for example - but that's how Hibernate create aliases - it was not meant to be in human readable format :)

Later (or rather earlier)

```
select
    acceptedna0_.pkey as pkey1_0_,
    acceptedna0_.name_accepted as name_acc2_0_,
    acceptedna0_.station_pkey as station_3_0_
```

means literally: "lets alias `pkey` colum of table `accepteddna0` (that's an alias) and call it `pkey1_0_`".

The same scenario - from now on you can use pkey1_0_ as column reference. Again it is not meant to be human readable but it fits Hibernate mapping process.

So in general, if you would copy-paste that strange SQL into PostgreSQL console or any other client, and replace ? with required values, query would be successful.